# Changing Language in Python SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, python-2.7, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am using SpeechRecognition in my Python application. However, it can only recognise English. I want it to recognise other languages too. I know it is possible somehow. Can anyone please help me with the syntax to change the language of speechrecognition in Python2.7
Please help! Thanks in advance. Here is my code so far :

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    try:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Language can be passed as argument to the recognize_google function

```
r.recognize_google(audio, language="hi-IN")
```

A list of supported language tags can be found in this StackOverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14302134

Answer (score 1):

So, You'll need to send the language code in config in your request

```
client = speech.SpeechClient()
audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=url)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
        language_code='es-US'   // Language code Español (Estados Unidos)
    )
response = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
```

For more details on available language models [please refer here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages)

Comment: I get this error Yet..... AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SpeechClient'

Comment: How are you importing the module ?

Comment: Your code is for google cloud speech to text api. Whereas I am using speech_recognition available on Pypi which uses google web speech. link is here : https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/