# How to set single_utterance for Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API using Speech Recognition with Python

Tags: python, google-api, python-3.6, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm writing a simple calculator using Google API and need to store the **recognized text from stream audio input** to process it further. The API has a **single_utterance** config option that seems to be extremely helpful, yet I can't find a way to set it.

In Cloud Text-to-Speech [library](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize) there's a line that says:

> set the single_utterance field to true in the [StreamingRecognitionConfig](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognitionConfig) object.

**Example code** on Speech Recognition [github](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/threaded_workers.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# NOTE: this example requires PyAudio because it uses the Microphone class

from threading import Thread
try:
    from queue import Queue  # Python 3 import
except ImportError:
    from Queue import Queue  # Python 2 import

import speech_recognition as sr


r = sr.Recognizer()
audio_queue = Queue()


def recognize_worker():
    # this runs in a background thread
    while True:
        audio = audio_queue.get()  # retrieve the next audio processing job from the main thread
        if audio is None: break  # stop processing if the main thread is done

        # received audio data, now we'll recognize it using Google Speech Recognition
        try:
            # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
            # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
            # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
            print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

        audio_queue.task_done()  # mark the audio processing job as completed in the queue


# start a new thread to recognize audio, while this thread focuses on listening
recognize_thread = Thread(target=recognize_worker)
recognize_thread.daemon = True
recognize_thread.start()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    try:
        while True:  # repeatedly listen for phrases and put the resulting audio on the audio processing job queue
            audio_queue.put(r.listen(source))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  # allow Ctrl + C to shut down the program
        pass

audio_queue.join()  # block until all current audio processing jobs are done
audio_queue.put(None)  # tell the recognize_thread to stop
recognize_thread.join()  # wait for the recognize_thread to actually stop
```

**Recognizer class** from the same [github](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py)

```
    def recognize_google(self, audio_data, key=None, language="en-US", pfilter=0, show_all=False):
        """
        Performs speech recognition on ``audio_data`` (an ``AudioData`` instance), using the Google Speech Recognition API.
        The Google Speech Recognition API key is specified by ``key``. If not specified, it uses a generic key that works out of the box. This should generally be used for personal or testing purposes only, as it **may be revoked by Google at any time**.
        To obtain your own API key, simply following the steps on the `API Keys <http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys>`__ page at the Chromium Developers site. In the Google Developers Console, Google Speech Recognition is listed as "Speech API".
        The recognition language is determined by ``language``, an RFC5646 language tag like ``"en-US"`` (US English) or ``"fr-FR"`` (International French), defaulting to US English. A list of supported language tags can be found in this `StackOverflow answer <http://stackoverflow.com/a/14302134>`__.
        The profanity filter level can be adjusted with ``pfilter``: 0 - No filter, 1 - Only shows the first character and replaces the rest with asterisks. The default is level 0.
        Returns the most likely transcription if ``show_all`` is false (the default). Otherwise, returns the raw API response as a JSON dictionary.
        Raises a ``speech_recognition.UnknownValueError`` exception if the speech is unintelligible. Raises a ``speech_recognition.RequestError`` exception if the speech recognition operation failed, if the key isn't valid, or if there is no internet connection.
        """
        assert isinstance(audio_data, AudioData), "``audio_data`` must be audio data"
        assert key is None or isinstance(key, str), "``key`` must be ``None`` or a string"
        assert isinstance(language, str), "``language`` must be a string"

        flac_data = audio_data.get_flac_data(
            convert_rate=None if audio_data.sample_rate >= 8000 else 8000,  # audio samples must be at least 8 kHz
            convert_width=2  # audio samples must be 16-bit
        )
        if key is None: key = "AIzaSyBOti4mM-6x9WDnZIjIeyEU21OpBXqWBgw"
        url = "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?{}".format(urlencode({
            "client": "chromium",
            "lang": language,
            "key": key,
            "pFilter": pfilter
        }))
        request = Request(url, data=flac_data, headers={"Content-Type": "audio/x-flac; rate={}".format(audio_data.sample_rate)})

        # obtain audio transcription results
        try:
            response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)
        except HTTPError as e:
            raise RequestError("recognition request failed: {}".format(e.reason))
        except URLError as e:
            raise RequestError("recognition connection failed: {}".format(e.reason))
        response_text = response.read().decode("utf-8")

        # ignore any blank blocks
        actual_result = []
        for line in response_text.split("\n"):
            if not line: continue
            result = json.loads(line)["result"]
            if len(result) != 0:
                actual_result = result[0]
                break

        # return results
        if show_all: return actual_result
        if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()

        if "confidence" in actual_result["alternative"]:
            # return alternative with highest confidence score
            best_hypothesis = max(actual_result["alternative"], key=lambda alternative: alternative["confidence"])
        else:
            # when there is no confidence available, we arbitrarily choose the first hypothesis.
            best_hypothesis = actual_result["alternative"][0]
        if "transcript" not in best_hypothesis: raise UnknownValueError()
        return best_hypothesis["transcript"]
```

The recognize_google() function in Recognizer class seems to have no passable argument that could set the single_utterance field to true.

Apart from the github, Google docs don't really include the Speech Recognition library.

I've tried to change the key in order to connect using my own API and take a look from console's perspective, but I've ran into problems there as well.

Comment: Here it is https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig

Comment: @Belegnar
From the github, part of recognize_google() function:
url = "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?{}".format(urlencode({
            "client": "chromium",
            "lang": language,
            "key": key,
            "pFilter": pfilter }))
In the docs I found Streaming Recognition Config and it includes single_utterance.  It seems the url and configs in the library need to be changed. Questions:
How's url encoded for streaming recognize and single_utterance?
Do I really have to change the library code?