# p5.speech.js: "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Speech')"

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, p5.js, speech-to-text

See below for the p5.speech.js library from the p5.js website:

```
/*! p5.speech.js v0.0.1 2015-06-12 */
/* updated v0.0.2 2017-10-17 */
/* updated v0.0.3 2022.1.7 */
/**
 * @module p5.speech
 * @submodule p5.speech
 * @for p5.speech
 * @main
 */

 (function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
      define('p5.Speech', ['p5'], function (p5) { (factory(p5));});
    else if (typeof exports === 'object')
      factory(require('../p5'));
    else
      factory(root['p5']);
  }(this, function (p5) {
  // =============================================================================
  //                         p5.Speech
  // =============================================================================
  
  
    /**
     * Base class for a Speech Synthesizer
     *
     * @class p5.Speech
     * @constructor
     */
    p5.Speech = function(_dv, _callback) {
  
      //
      // speech synthesizers consist of a single synthesis engine
      // per window instance, and a variable number of 'utterance'
      // objects, which can be cached and re-used for, e.g.
      // auditory UI.
      //
      // this implementation assumes a monolithic (one synth,
      // one phrase at a time) system.
      //
  
      // make a speech synthizer (this will load voices):
      this.synth = window.speechSynthesis;
  
      // make an utterance to use with this synthesizer:
      this.utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  
      this.isLoaded = 0; // do we have voices yet?
  
      // do we queue new utterances upon firing speak()
      // or interrupt what's speaking:
      this.interrupt = false;
  
      // callback properties to be filled in within the p5 sketch
      // if the author needs custom callbacks:
      this.onLoad; // fires when voices are loaded and synth is ready
      this.onStart; // fires when an utterance begins...
      this.onPause; // ...is paused...
      this.onResume; // ...resumes...
      this.onEnd; // ...and ends.
  
      this.voices = []; // array of available voices (dependent on browser/OS)
  
      // first parameter of constructor is an initial voice selector
      this.initvoice;
      if(_dv !== undefined) this.initvoice=_dv;
      if(_callback !== undefined) this.onLoad =_callback;
  
      var that = this; // aliasing 'this' into a fixed variable
  
      // onvoiceschanged() fires automatically when the synthesizer
      // is configured and has its voices loaded.  you don't need
      // to wait for this if you're okay with the default voice.
      //
      // we use this function to load the voice array and bind our
      // custom callback functions.
      window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
        if(that.isLoaded==0) { // run only once
          that.voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
          that.isLoaded = 1; // we're ready
          console.log("p5.Speech: voices loaded!");
  
          if(that.initvoice!=undefined) {
            that.setVoice(that.initvoice); // set a custom initial voice
            console.log("p5.Speech: initial voice: " + that.initvoice);
          }
  
          // fire custom onLoad() callback, if it exists:
          if(that.onLoad!=undefined) that.onLoad();
  
          //
          // bind other custom callbacks:
          //
  
          that.utterance.onstart = function(e) {
            //console.log("STARTED");
            if(that.onStart!=undefined) that.onStart(e);
          };
          that.utterance.onpause = function(e) {
            //console.log("PAUSED");
            if(that.onPause!=undefined) that.onPause(e);
          };
          that.utterance.onresume = function(e) {
            //console.log("RESUMED");
            if(that.onResume!=undefined) that.onResume(e);
          };
          that.utterance.onend = function(e) {
            //console.log("ENDED");
            if(that.onEnd!=undefined) that.onEnd(e);
          };
        }
      };
  
    };     // end p5.Speech constructor
  
  
    // listVoices() - dump voice names to javascript console:
    p5.Speech.prototype.listVoices = function() {
      if(this.isLoaded)
      {
        for(var i = 0;i<this.voices.length;i++)
        {
          console.log(this.voices[i].name);
        }
      }
      else
      {
          console.log("p5.Speech: voices not loaded yet!")
      }
    };
  
    // setVoice() - assign voice to speech synthesizer, by name
    // (using voices found in the voices[] array), or by index.
    p5.Speech.prototype.setVoice = function(_v) {
      // type check so you can set by label or by index:
      if(typeof(_v)=='string') this.utterance.voice = this.voices.filter(function(v) { return v.name == _v; })[0];
      else if(typeof(_v)=='number') this.utterance.voice = this.voices[Math.min(Math.max(_v,0),this.voices.length-1)];
    };
  
    // volume of voice. API range 0.0-1.0.
    p5.Speech.prototype.setVolume = function(_v) {
      this.utterance.volume = Math.min(Math.max(_v, 0.0), 1.0);
    };
  
    // rate of voice.  not all voices support this feature.
    // API range 0.1-2.0.  voice will crash out of bounds.
    p5.Speech.prototype.setRate = function(_v) {
      this.utterance.rate = Math.min(Math.max(_v, 0.1), 2.0);
    };
  
    // pitch of voice.  not all voices support this feature.
    // API range >0.0-2.0.  voice will crash out of bounds.
    p5.Speech.prototype.setPitch = function(_v) {
      this.utterance.pitch = Math.min(Math.max(_v, 0.01), 2.0);
    };
  
    // sets the language of the voice.
    p5.Speech.prototype.setLang = function(_lang) {
      this.utterance.lang = _lang;
  }
  
    // speak a phrase through the current synthesizer:
    p5.Speech.prototype.speak = function(_phrase) {
      if(this.interrupt) this.synth.cancel();
      this.utterance.text = _phrase;
  
      this.synth.speak(this.utterance);
    };
  
    // not working...
    p5.Speech.prototype.pause = function() {
      this.synth.pause();
    };
  
    // not working...
    p5.Speech.prototype.resume = function() {
      this.synth.resume();
    };
  
    // stop current utterance:
    p5.Speech.prototype.stop = function() {
      // not working...
      //this.synth.stop();
      this.synth.cancel();
    };
  
    // kill synthesizer completely, clearing any queued utterances:
    p5.Speech.prototype.cancel = function() {
      this.synth.cancel(); // KILL SYNTH
    };
  
    // Setting callbacks with functions instead
    p5.Speech.prototype.started = function(_cb) {
     this.onStart = _cb;
    }
  
    p5.Speech.prototype.ended = function(_cb) {
      this.onEnd = _cb;
    }
  
    p5.Speech.prototype.paused = function(_cb) {
      this.onPause = _cb;
    }
  
    p5.Speech.prototype.resumed = function(_cb) {
      this.onResume = _cb;
    }
  
  // =============================================================================
  //                         p5.SpeechRec
  // =============================================================================
  
  
    /**
     * Base class for a Speech Recognizer
     *
     * @class p5.SpeechRec
     * @constructor
     */
    p5.SpeechRec = function(_lang, _callback) {
  
      //
      // speech recognition consists of a recognizer object per
      // window instance that returns a JSON object containing
      // recognition.  this JSON object grows when the synthesizer
      // is in 'continuous' mode, with new recognized phrases
      // appended into an internal array.
      //
      // this implementation returns the full JSON, but also a set
      // of simple, query-ready properties containing the most
      // recently recognized speech.
      //
  
      // make a recognizer object.
      if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
        this.rec = new (window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.mozSpeechRecognition || window.msSpeechRecognition)();
      }
      else {
        this.rec = new Object();
        console.log("p5.SpeechRec: Speech Recognition not supported in this browser.");
      }
  
      // first parameter is language model (defaults to empty=U.S. English)
      // no list of valid models in API, but it must use BCP-47.
      // here's some hints:
      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257598/what-are-language-codes-for-voice-recognition-languages-in-chromes-implementati
      if(_lang !== undefined) this.rec.lang=_lang;
  
      // callback properties to be filled in within the p5 sketch
      // if the author needs custom callbacks:
      this.onResult; // fires when something has been recognized
      this.onStart; // fires when the recognition system is started...
      this.onError; // ...has a problem (e.g. the mic is shut off)...
      this.onEnd; // ...and ends (in non-continuous mode).
      if(_callback !== undefined) this.onResult=_callback;
  
      // recognizer properties:
  
      // continous mode means the object keeps recognizing speech,
      // appending new tokens to the internal JSON.
      this.continuous = false;
      // interimResults means the object will report (i.e. fire its
      // onresult() callback) more frequently, rather than at pauses
      // in microphone input.  this gets you quicker, but less accurate,
      // results.
      this.interimResults = false;
  
      // result data:
  
      // resultJSON:
      // this is a full JSON returned by onresult().  it consists of a
      // SpeechRecognitionEvent object, which contains a (wait for it)
      // SpeechRecognitionResultList.  this is an array.  in continuous
      // mode, it will be appended to, not cleared.  each element is a
      // SpeechRecognition result, which contains a (groan)
      // SpeechRecognitionAlternative, containing a 'transcript' property.
      // the 'transcript' is the recognized phrase.  have fun.
      this.resultJSON;
      // resultValue:
      // validation flag which indicates whether the recognizer succeeded.
      // this is *not* a metric of speech clarity, but rather whether the
      // speech recognition system successfully connected to and received
      // a response from the server.  you can construct an if() around this
      // if you're feeling worried.
      this.resultValue;
      // resultString:
      // the 'transcript' of the most recently recognized speech as a simple
      // string.  this will be blown out and replaced at every firing of the
      // onresult() callback.
      this.resultString;
      // resultConfidence:
      // the 'confidence' (0-1) of the most recently recognized speech, e.g.
      // that it reflects what was actually spoken.  you can use this to filter
      // out potentially bogus recognition tokens.
      this.resultConfidence;
  
      var that = this; // aliasing 'this' into a fixed variable
  
      // onresult() fires automatically when the recognition engine
      // detects speech, or times out trying.
      //
      // it fills up a JSON array internal to the webkitSpeechRecognition
      // object.  we reference it over in our struct here, and also copy
      // out the most recently detected phrase and confidence value.
      this.rec.onresult = function(e) {
        that.resultJSON = e; // full JSON of callback event
        that.resultValue = e.returnValue; // was successful?
        // store latest result in top-level object struct
        that.resultString = e.results[e.results.length-1][0].transcript.trim();
        that.resultConfidence = e.results[e.results.length-1][0].confidence;
        if(that.onResult!=undefined) that.onResult();
      };
  
      // fires when the recognition system starts (i.e. when you 'allow'
      // the mic to be used in the browser).
      this.rec.onstart = function(e) {
        if(that.onStart!=undefined) that.onStart(e);
      };
      // fires on a client-side error (server-side errors are expressed
      // by the resultValue in the JSON coming back as 'false').
      this.rec.onerror = function(e) {
        if(that.onError!=undefined) that.onError(e);
      };
      // fires when the recognition finishes, in non-continuous mode.
      this.rec.onend = function() {
        if(that.onEnd!=undefined) that.onEnd();
      };
  
    }; // end p5.SpeechRec constructor
  
    // start the speech recognition engine.  this will prompt a
    // security dialog in the browser asking for permission to
    // use the microphone.  this permission will persist throughout
    // this one 'start' cycle.  if you need to recognize speech more
    // than once, use continuous mode rather than firing start()
    // multiple times in a single script.
    p5.SpeechRec.prototype.start = function(_continuous, _interim) {
      if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
        if(_continuous !== undefined) this.continuous = _continuous;
        if(_interim !== undefined) this.interimResults = _interim;
        this.rec.continuous = this.continuous;
        this.rec.interimResults = this.interimResults;
        this.rec.start();
      }
    };
  
    // Add function to stop the speech recognition from continued listening
    p5.SpeechRec.prototype.stop = function()  {
      if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
        this.rec.stop();
      }
    };
  
  }));
```

I downloaded the above recently and tried to create the function below:

```
function setup() {
    noCanvas();
    var voice = p5.Speech();
    voice.speak('Hello Everyone!');
}
```

But I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know why p5.Speech is undefined here and how I can go about correcting this issue? I'm trying to build an application that will perform speech recognition and then call a function but unfortunately I am unable to do that with this error.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
// set your var outside the setup enviroment
var voice;

// then set the value using 'new'
function setup() {
    noCanvas();
    voice = new p5.Speech();
    voice.speak('Hello Everyone!');
}
```